# Does Azure function support bindings for Cosmos DB with Mongo Api? Are there any workarounds apart from using MongoClient

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Does Azure function work with triggers,input,output bindings for CosmosDB with MongoApi? Are there any way past this apart from using a MongoClient?

Answer (score 1):

As documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2), Cosmos DB bindings are specific to the SQL API.

For any other binding (such as MongoDB API, which you're asking about, or Cassandra, Gremlin, etc), you'd need to use a language-specific client SDK. In your case you'd need to work with a MongoDB client from your Azure Function.